# Extended input functionality using gets()?

Tags: command-line, command-history

I'm searching for a possibility that adds a command history as well as the possibility to edit a line already typed to a program that takes input from the standard input.

Example:

```
cat > example.txt
This is the first or third line I have typed. Both lines are identical.
This is teh second line I have typed. The word "the" is typed correc
```

In the situation shown above, I'd like to use the cursor keys to navigate to the typo mistake, correct it, press the "End" key and finish the line.

Because the third and the first line have the same text, some command history would also be nice.

(Of course I don't need that for `cat` but for another command-line based tool.)

Does some program exist that adds these features to "regular" programs?

My idea was to write a tool myself that provides a command history, which would work like this:

```
command_history | cat > example.txt
```

However, I don't want to spent any time on this if such a tool already exists or if I could reach my target by simply doing some configuration changes.

Comment: `rlwrap`: `rlwrap cat`

Comment: @mosvy Thank you very much. This seems to be exactly what I need.